# How to convert time object to minutes in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have an output from a database(postgreSQL) in python. The time is encoded as timestamptz. We need to be able to convert the time into just minutes.

> 2015-07-09 13:45:08.266520+00:00

For example this would be 825 minutes.

I'm having issues with the datetime.datetime formating, I just need to be able to drop everything but hours and minutes and then convert to minutes.

```
time_format = '%H:%M'

time1 = datetime.strptime('2015-07-09 13:45:08.266520+00:00', time_format)
```

So I'm trying to sort a big list of times into certain intervals. I need these times to be in just minutes in order to do any math on them, I do not want to have to mess with time anymore. Thats why I'm trying to just covert them into minutes by taking the hours * 60 + minutes. Since this is in a time format I cannot do any of that.

Comment: *"having issues"* - what issues, and with what code?

Comment: How would this be 825 minutes?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to do. So you want to convert the timestamp you're getting from your DB into minutes. Basically 0:00 would be 0, 1:00 would be 60 and so on.

Timestamps are standard, so a dirty hack you could do is just pull the indices of the relevant information that you want and go from there.

```
time = "2015-07-09 13:45:08.266520+00:00"
data = time[11:18]
print data //Will be 13:45:08
```

Then you can do data operations from there.

Answer (score 2):

Substract the `DateTime` from a `DateTime` with the the reference point in time, extract the `total_seconds` from the resulting `TimeDelta` and divide by 60.

*(You did not give any code. So I can't give any code based on your's.)*

Answer (score 1):

`dateutil` takes a lot of the headache out of parsing a ISO 8601 stamp:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2015-07-09 13:45:08.266520+00:00')
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 9, 13, 45, 8, 266520, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Since you want the answer to be '825 minutes', algebraically, you must be seeking an offset from an epoch mark:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> mark=dateutil.parser.parse('2015-07-09 13:45:08.266520+00:00')-dt.timedelta(minutes=825)
>>> mark
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 9, 0, 0, 8, 266520, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

So now use `mark` as the basis to calculate minute offsets. (You probably mean to ignore microseconds in the base time mark)